# String manipulation via angular directive without a template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to take a list of plaintext tweets (e.g., "@Stackoverflow is cool #hashtag"), pass it through an `ng-repeat`, and then apply a custom directive (or filter) to alter the string to something like "[@Stackoverflow](http://twitter.com/stackoverflow/) is cool [#hashtag](https://twitter.com/search?q=#hashtag&src=typd/)"

So, I've tried a filter, and it works well except it doesn't play nice with raw html and I've read that this is the job for a directive, anyways.

So, the filter (called like: `{{ tweet | parseTweetTags }}`):

```
(function (app) {

    app.filter("parseTweetTags", function () {
        return function (text) {
            return text.parseUrl().parseUsername().parseHashtag()
        }
    });

}(angular.module('twitterApp')));
```

Now, I guess I'd like to make it a directive instead, and call it like `<div parse-tweet-tags="tweet.text"></div>` (or even without the `="tweet.text"` - I'm not sure what a best practice is) from inside an `ng-repeat`

Here's where I'm at with that, but I think it's pretty far off:

```
(function (app) {
    app.directive('parseTweetTags', function () {
        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            var tweet;
            function parseTweet() {
                element.text(tweet.parseURL().parseUsername().parseHashtag());
            }

            scope.$watch(attrs.tweet, function (value) {
                tweet = value;
            });
        }

        return {
            link: link
        }
    });
}(angular.module('twitterApp')));
```

And the HTML would hopefully look like this, there is no `ng-model`

```
<div ng-controller="tweetsController">
    <div ng-repeat="tweet in tweets">
        <div parse-tweet-tags="tweet.text"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**tl;dr**

How can I simply pass a string, do a simple operation on it in a directive, and return it, without a template

Comment: Sounds like a filter is probably the way to go... Might be worth looking at the [linky](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.filter:linky) source, [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.4/src/ngSanitize/filter/linky.js#L103)

Comment: The answer was using a filter, but I wanted to do more than just the links.  I needed to modify my filter shown above to take `$sce` and then the return statement was `return $sce.trustAsHtml(text.parseUrl().parseUsername().parseHashtag());` and the html was `<div ng-bind-html="tweet.text | parseTweetTags"></div>`

Comment: you never call `parseTweet()` in directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a slight modification to the filter and the way it is bound to the HTML I was able to get this going.

First, the change to the filter, to pass in $sce and call $sce.trustAsHtml()

```
(function (app) {
    app.filter("parseTweetTags", function ($sce) {
        return function (text) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text.parseURL().parseUsername().parseHashtag());
        }
    });
}(angular.module('twitterApp')));
```

And the change to the html:

```
<div ng-controller="tweetsController">
    <div ng-repeat="tweet in tweets">
        <div ng-bind-html="tweet.text | parseTweetTags"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```